# Calling server side method from client returns undefined

Tags: meteor, reactjs

I have a simple validation method on the server side which returns true or false. I want to call this from the client to validate input and avoid having too much logic exposed on the client side.

Originally I had this. But it never worked and the value of `result` would always be `undefined`.

```
//methods.js
Meteor.methods({
  validate(input) {
    return GuestList.find({invitationCode: input}).count() == 1;
  }
}

//component.jsx
component = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      valid: false,
      data: null
    }
  },

  handleLoginSubmit(input){    
    var result = Meteor.call('validateInviteCode', input);
    this.setState({ valid: result });    
  },

  render(){
    return this.state.valid ? <MyApp data={this.state.data}/> :  <Login callbackToContainer={this.handleLoginSubmit} />;
  }
});
```

So then I tried the following. In debug if I placed a breakpoint on the `return res` line I could see that after a few seconds it would come back with a value from the server but otherwise it was `undefined` as well.

```
handleLoginSubmit(input){    
    var result = Meteor.call('validate', input, function(err, res) {
      if(err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      else {
       return res;
      }
    });

    this.setState({ valid: result });    
  },
```

I know this all comes down to async vs sync function calls. In this case, I really just want the client behavior to act synchronously. I saw some similar posts and people suggested using futures. But I am not sure if I should be putting them in the server method or on the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct that this is an async issue. On the client side you do not have Futures available, so the result of Meteor.call() will always be undefined (http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_call):

> On the client, if you do not pass a callback and you are not inside a stub, call will return undefined, and you will have no way to get the return value of the method. That is because the client doesn't have fibers, so there is not actually any way it can block on the remote execution of a method.

Can you just set the state this way?

```
handleLoginSubmit(input){ 

  Meteor.call('validate', input, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      // do something better here
      return console.log(err);
    }

    this.setState({ valid: res });
  });  
},
```

Comment: I gave this a try, and initially it threw an exception complaining that `setState()` could not be resolved, but I added `var self = this` above the block then it worked.